# Javascript access parent public variable

Tags: javascript, class, variables, subclass

I am trying to get subclass to access parent variable. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
function a() {
    this.val = 600;
    var self = this;

    this.c = new b();

    this.d = function() {
        console.log("P:");
        this.c.p();
    }
}

function b() {
    this.val2 = 1;
    this.p = function() {
        console.log(self.val);
    }
}

var test = new a();
test.d();
```

Comment: Error: `self` does not exist in the scope of function `b`. `self` exists only in scope of `a`. Try assigning `this.b.self = self` and access it from `b().p()`as `this.self` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `b` function, `self` is undefined since it doesn't create a closure. This means you can't reference `self`.

The way you coded it doesn't create closures.

If you do it like this it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/y2A93/

```
function a() {
    this.val = 600;
    var self = this;

    this.c = new b();
    this.c.self = self; // create `self` variable

    this.d = function() {
        console.log("P:");
        this.c.p();
    }
}

function b() {
    this.val2 = 1;
    this.p = function() {
        console.log(this.self.val); // create closure that passes `self` from `b` to `p`.
    }
}

var test = new a();
test.d();
```

What I do is create a `self` variable in the instance of `b` called `c`. Than I create a closure by accessing the `self` in `b` from an inner function; `p` in this case.

Comment: oops this.b isnt suppose to be there, supposed to be this.c

but how would I go about making this code work?

Comment: Ok, still, my first point is viable. `self` is undefined there because there is not `closure` create. Do you know what a closure is or you want me to explain ?

Comment: Glad you do :) ! It is not that hard. Just hard to read. There are some great articles explaining this in details if you google it. P.S. if it helped you, don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Error: self does not exist in the scope of function b. self exists only in scope of a. Try assigning `this.c.parent = self` (or constructing this.c with that value) and access it from 
`(new b()).p()` as this.parent instead

Try:

```
function a() {
    this.val = 600;
    var self = this;

    this.c = new b(self);

    this.d = function() {
        console.log("P:");
        this.c.p();
    }
}

function b(parent) {
    this.val2 = 1;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.p = function() {
        console.log(this.parent.val);
    }
}

var test = new a();
test.d();
```